# Nodemailer inline-style not always working

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to send a mail via nodemailer with some texts and images,
it all worked fine until i had to center an image and then i sterted to run into some weird bugs with the stylings, i have 2 examples that just doesn't work :

1. the following code is my wrapper, and when it sents the part of 'flex-direction: column' is being ommited and in the devtools i see only the 'direction: ltr; display: flex;' as the inline style :

`<div style='direction: ltr; display: flex; flex-direction: column;'></div>`

2. the following code is an image i tried to center ( after the flex part didnt work as expected ) but this time the part of 'transform' is being ommited and i only get the margin :

`<img src="cid:image2@cid" style='margin-left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, 0)'/>`

maybe someone have an idea what am i missing here ?

thanks

Comment: try to set `margin: auto` into your img element without transform so  `<img src="cid:image2@cid" style='margin:auto;'/>` The css you made should work if you set position absolute in your img and then left:50%; transform:translate(-50%,0);

Comment: this is what i did at first but it didnt center it..

Comment: i dont want the element to be on absolute position, and my css does work the problam is that for some reason the transform part is being ommited like its a typo or something

Comment: did it answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here 2 option in 1 snippet, I would recommand to always use table in email structure.

PS: I was adding max-width and height to image to show it well on my demo. You can remove that.

```css
table {
  width:100%;
}
tbody {
  width:100%;
}
tr {
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!------------------ 1st solution -------------------->
<div style='direction: ltr; display: flex; flex-direction: column;'>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/06/20/25/dog-3204497_960_720.jpg" style='margin:auto; height:auto; max-width:120px;'/>
</div>

<!------------------ 2nd solution -------------------->
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 20px;">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/06/20/25/dog-3204497_960_720.jpg" style="height:auto; max-width:120px;" />
        <div style="padding-top: 30px;">TEST TEXT #1</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```